# Populate country list with respective two letter and three letter code in c#

Tags: c#, list, culture

Can any one please help in populating the list of country names, its respective two letter code and three letter codes.. I tried the below snippet, but its giving me incomplete results.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        foreach (CultureInfo ci in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures & ~CultureTypes.NeutralCultures))
        {
            try
            {
                RegionInfo myRI1 = new RegionInfo(ci.LCID);
                list.Add(String.Format("{0,-12}{1,-12}{2}", myRI1.TwoLetterISORegionName, myRI1.EnglishName, myRI1.ThreeLetterISORegionName));
            }
            catch { }
       }

    list.Sort();  // sort by name
        // write to console
    foreach (string str in list)
        Console.WriteLine(str);

    Console.WriteLine("Total Countries" + list.Count.ToString());
    Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Before I take a closer look: what do you mean by "incomplete results"?

Comment: In what way are the results "*incomplete*"?

Comment: Your [code](http://ideone.com/4WJsRu) clearly shows there is an issue loading the `RegionInfo` from the `CultureInfo` being returned by `GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures & ~CultureTypes.NeutralCultures))`. You should step through your loop and see why it's returning empty `RegionInfo`, generally it's better practise to use `CultureTypes.SpecificCultures`.

Comment: You should also remove that nasty `try...catch` if any exceptions are thrown you won't know about them.

Comment: As per the above snippet, it does not give me the list of all the countries, some are repeated, and the total count of the list is only 210. I think, this is because i have used the regioninfo to extract the list.

Answer (score 2):

If you really must retrieve this information using C#, this is how I'd do it:

```
var regions = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures)
    .Where(c => !c.IsNeutralCulture && c.LCID != 0x7f)
    .Select(c => new RegionInfo(c.LCID))
    .GroupBy(r => r.TwoLetterISORegionName) // This is an alternative to using Distinct
    .Select(g => g.First())                 // It's probably not very efficient, but the list is so small anyway.
    .OrderBy(r => r.TwoLetterISORegionName)
    .ToList();
```

(The culture with the LCID 0x7f is the `InvariantCulture`, which doesn't have an associated RegionInfo.)

This gives only 127 countries on my computer. Your method gives a lot more results because there are many instances of multiple `CultureInfos` that share the same `RegionInfo`. For instance, there are four different `CultureInfos` that point to the `RegionInfo` for Spain: `ca-ES` (Catalan), `eu-ES` (Basque), `gl-ES` (Galician) and `es-ES` (Spanish). This is because `CultureInfo` is primarily concerned with languages, and languages and regions don't need to match up.

There are way more than 127 countries in the world. The problem is that approaching this by using `CultureInfo` and `RegionInfo` can only ever tell you about the countries that your computer happens to know about, which is unlikely to be a complete list. What's more, as the name `RegionInfo` suggests, they aren't necessarily even countries or nations. For example, one of the `RegionInfo` entries on my computer is "Caribbean", with a TwoLetterISORegionName of `029` (which I have to admit is rather strange). The Caribbean is clearly not a country.

A better way to solve your problem is to look up a list of countries elsewhere, like, say, [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries) and store them in a table somewhere in your program.